# webpackPrefetch expected true or a number, but received: false. (magic comment)

Tags: typescript, webpack, lazy-loading

I want to disabled prefetch for some dynamics imports in webpack

here is my code

```
await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "lang-[request]" */
    /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
    /* webpackPrefetch: false */
    `./${lang}`
  )
```

but I have this warning

`webpackPrefetch` expected true or a number, but received: false.

and in my html I have always the link rel prefetch for the import

How can I solve this problem ?